# trigger-after insert on table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one master table in oracle. Whenever new rows are inserted into this table, i need to distribute the new data to other tables. So, i created a trigger- after insert on table- statement trigger to distribute the data to their respective tables and in this process i need to generate report  of number of new rows inserted into each table and the date. i'm generating a report by writing it to a file.
How do i keep track of count of new rows inserted? here is my code...

```
create or replace trigger distribute_trig

after insert on table_name
call procedure1
```

Comment: If the destination tables have an `inserted_at` timestamp in them, you can just query them for the information.  However, I'm a bit wary of using a trigger on a _table_ for this - normally you use a **view**, with an instead-of trigger on it (or maybe not even the trigger, if the query is simple enough).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: i receive millions of records and i have an id in the master table which determines the destination table.There are too many destination tables which i dynamically get it from another table. i have a receivedmonth field in destination but data arrives several times  in a month. and i dont understand how can using view be any help. before i had to this manually and there was a chance to  miss the data.

Comment: The implication of splitting up data in one table to multiple destination tables is that the destination tables are some sort of normalization of the data - that is, usually the source table would be constructed by a query - hence using a view.  Your question is really about aggregating results, which is best done by querying the tables themselves - if you have a date/time column with sufficient resolution you roll up based on that.  Your only other option is to maintain a count in another table, which will effectively serialize throughput (slow stuff **way** down).

Comment: What you mean when saying "keep track"? Is it similar case like in [**this SQLFiddle example**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bfff3/3)?